# not able compile the code "nativeEntityManagerFactory" is giving errors

Tags: java, spring, java-8, tomcat9

the error in the below lines:-

```
this.nativeEntityManagerFactory =
                provider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(this.persistenceUnitInfo, getJpaPropertyMap());
        postProcessEntityManagerFactory(this.nativeEntityManagerFactory, this.persistenceUnitInfo);

        return this.nativeEntityManagerFactory;
```

the eclipse suggestion are below none of them make sense to me: -

```
     Multiple markers at this line
    - The field AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.nativeEntityManagerFactory is not visible
    - nativeEntityManagerFactory cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

i tried compiling the code to check the compilation error below is the compilation error:-

```
      /D:/repo_upgrade_tomcat_9/backend/src/main/java/com/backend/util/SLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:[232,21] nativeEntityManagerFactory has private access in org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean
```

Spring version used 5.3.27.

I'm using jdk8, tomcat9, spring v5.3.27.
I tried changing the version of hibernate and spring.

Complete hibernate depedency used:-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: There is only an API not a hibernate implementation. No `hibernate-validator` is not a JPA implementation `hibernate-entitymanager` is.

Comment: please check the edited question. i have added hibernate-entitymanager still getting error

Comment: resolved this error by adding "private EntityManagerFactory nativeEntityManagerFactory;"

Comment: Your hibernate versions are a mess and trouble waiting to happen, the versions should generally match (except for the `hibernate-validator` one).